# How can i proxy to SSL backend without specifiyng cert files?

Tags: ssl, nginx, playframework-2.1, reverse-proxy

I have an Play 2.1.x application which signs itself using JKS. It's up, running and available at `domain.com:9443`, I need to proxy it with **nginx**, as there will be more apps on the same machine, (*therefore can't run it just on port `443`*) I added the nginx config in hope that `proxy_pass` with `https` will allow me to just proxy it to client

```
upstream backend-secure {
    server 0.0.0.0:9443;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name domain.com;

        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


        location / {
                proxy_pass  https://backend-secure;
        }

}
```

Unfortunately when trying to open `https://domain.com` in browser I only get log in `nginx/error.log` like:

> no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 123.123.123.123, server: 0.0.0.0:443

Is there a way to make it working or only option is using common way for nginx SSL + using `http` backend?

**Edit:** It's EV, multidomain certificate if it matters.

Comment: Dup of [Nginx reverse proxy without SSL termination](https://serverfault.com/questions/655259/nginx-reverse-proxy-without-ssl-termination)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only option for proxy is to have the certificate inside nginx. Another option would be to just TCP forward the connection outside of ngnix, but then you will not get any of the X-Real-IP, X-Forwarded-For etc stuff.

Comment: Second option is not acceptable (real IP is required in the app) I'll choose first, but additional question: my app should sign itself with `jks` and then I should set `proxy_pass` as `https`, right?

Comment: There are two ways: you can let the proxy speak https to the client and forward it as http to the server (within trusted network) or you could do also the forwarding to the server as https. The latter case needs more resources because data need to be encrypted again by the proxy and decrypted by the server and it will be slower because SSL connection setup needs more handshakes but you can use it over untrusted networks.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich How would you configure the latter? Simply `proxy_pass https://..` does not work (i.e. when I use an invalid cert it still works fine). nginx version 1.6.2..